# Duplicate dialog and quoted text look very similar

Tags: discussion, design

At first glance, specially when the quote is the first line of the question, they're both (almost) look the same.

Marked as duplicate:

[image]

Quote:

[image]

I manually wrote the duplicate message as a quote to demonstrate the issue :) but they look similar even when the text is not identical.

It would be great if one of the two designed will be changed to be a little more different.

Comment: Seems like a non-issue given that there is usually no chance of confusing the one with the other, if the quote is not specifically crafted to contain the same text as the other. Even then, the difference is somewhat obvious due to the rest of the styling of the duplicate message. And currently, there are way worse design issues that need fixing...

Comment: @l4mpi when you open a question, you see a yellow box, before your mind begins to read the content, the confusion begins.

Comment: So what? In the extremely rare case that someone, for whatever reason, crafts a quote to look like the duplicate message, this is easily detected (e.g. by the missing close notice on the bottom). In most other cases where quote blocks are used on SO as part of a question, I'd wager they're usually misused anyways and can be edited out. So if that confuses you, simply use your edit privileges and make it less confusing.

Comment: [very related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212992/238586)

Comment: Before I *open a question* that has been closed (for whatever reason) I usually see that in the question title before I have to worry about the fact I *see a yellow box*. There's not much confusion.

Comment: @KenWhite Sometimes it takes a time until [duplicate] appears next to the question.. it doesn't appear immediately after it's marked as a duplicate.